No Internet, Secured | I've tried any solution there was, still no internet
I've been having this issue where I can't connect to the internet at all no matter what solution I've tried.
It keeps on saying "No Internet, Secured", even if it's using Wi-Fi, Ethernet, Hotspot, nothing works.
I have tried...

Resetting "Network Setup Service" in Services
Re-Installing the Networking Drivers 3 times (Device Manager)
Doing a "Network Reset" in Settings
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes but says "General failure"
Resetting network configuration
Using these commands below:

ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /release
netsh winsock reset catalog
All to no avail.
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /renew

Windows IP Configuration

No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 12 while it has its media disconnected.

No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 13 while it has its media disconnected.

An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.

An error occurred while renewing interface VMware Network Adapter VMnet1 : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.

An error occurred while renewing interface VMware Network Adapter VMnet8 : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.

An error occurred while renewing interface Wi-Fi : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>

ipconfig /all
C:\Users\mauve>ipconfig /all
 
Windows IP Configuration
 
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-QLHI1E4
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
 
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:
 
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5E-A6-E6-26-4D-17
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13:
 
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5C-A6-E6-26-4D-17
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::dac5:9dbf:36b3:2db5%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.200.103(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 09 ноември 2024 г. 12:14:49
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 10 ноември 2024 г. 0:14:34
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.200.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.200.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 367056222
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2E-C0-E7-9D-E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.200.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
 
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:
 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::42d4:3bb4:11ef:746b%14(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.199.117(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 402673750
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2E-C0-E7-9D-E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
 
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:
 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::744f:40f4:7ff2:fc94%27(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.117.230(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 419450966
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2E-C0-E7-9D-E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
 
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8188EU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5C-A6-E6-26-4D-17
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3263:88d9:9fe4:40d6%25(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.130.146(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 375170790
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2E-C0-E7-9D-E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
 
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Ethernet):
 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-82-80-91
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cc56:30ff:2ac8:76e9%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.112.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 218109277
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2E-C0-E7-9D-E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
 
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):
 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-3E-44-A2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3382:3068:909:c034%34(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.192.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 570430813
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2E-C0-E7-9D-E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
 
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (VMware Network ):
 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-A2-50-A1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cc32:e8b1:e61c:20b0%38(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.208.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 637539677
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2E-C0-E7-9D-E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
 
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (VMware Network ) 2:
 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-41-F4-17
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::490b:d3ac:a5ff:34bd%42(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.160.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 704648541
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2E-C0-E7-9D-E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
 
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Wi-Fi):
 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-15-2C-2B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d3e1:7ed4:779e:dc11%59(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.64.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 989861213
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2E-C0-E7-9D-E0-D5-5E-6E-4E-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
 
C:\Users\mauve>

I have Debian dual-booted with my Windows 10 installation. Networking works fine and pings correctly. Currently using Debian to write this.

can you create a new administrator account, then login and repeat the same tests you did above? Don't connect wifi, just ethernet.

@JohnnyVegas The mauve account already is an administrator account, and I've been using wifi and ethernet for all the steps I've done. I'll give it a shot later since I have my birthday party to attend to.

happy birthday! Creating a new account gives you a clean user profile, which makes troubleshooting far easier.

Seems you have some virtual Ethernet devices set up (for VMware, etc), so my guess is something funky is going on - Windows is probably trying to use the virtual Ethernet ports which then have no internet (hence Connected, No Internet, Secured). You might have to dig into Network & Sharing center, try and see if you can set your physical Ethernet as default, or at least (temporarily!) disable the VMware ones to at least see if that was the culprit?

Yay me, the answer was under my nose after all.
The firewall probably had to do something about the problem, but ehh...
I had to run these commands in this order:
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
netsh advfirewall reset
ipconfig /flushdns
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netsh advfirewall reset
Ok.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ping google.com

    Pinging google.com [172.217.17.110] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.17.110: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=117
Reply from 172.217.17.110: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=117
Reply from 172.217.17.110: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=117
Reply from 172.217.17.110: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=117

Ping statistics for 172.217.17.110:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 23ms, Maximum = 24ms, Average = 23ms
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

I forgot to mention that having the Ethernet connected yielded a "Unidentified network, No internet" result. Soz!
I got the solution from the 3rd reply from this thread. Thank you all for trying to help me, it was a pleasure and pain trying to troubleshoot this issue :-)
